# How to make a python script to run only on specific time on Heroku?

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, procfile

I have a python script(Do something on with `selenium` & send the result to my what'sapp `[Used Twilio API]`) and I hosted it on `Heroku` & scheduled to run `one time per day`. It runs on scheduled time as expected but it also runs on other time as well(more than 6 times per day). I don't want to run it other than scheduled time. How can I make it run only on scheduled time?

```
Procfile:

web: python my_script.py
```

Apart from that, I have `requirements.txt & my_script.py` in my directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `time` module and the `while` loop to check whether the current time  is equal to the time that you want.

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
desired_time = '13:28'
while True:
    if strftime("%H:%M", gmtime()) == desired_time:
        main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided might be the simplest possible option. Here's what I used in my personal project.

You can use [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), to schedule the task to run at an interval.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(my_logger, 'interval', seconds=3)
    scheduler.start()
```