# Python automation project to run in the background

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, automation, background

i just started working with python and with some scripts to automate some tasks. I manage to create a web scraper using selenium that notifies me daily with the latest news via a mail . Now the script works great if i run it manually , but my question is : How can i make the script to run automatically every day , and what option would you recomand . I know that you can use TaskScheduler and program it , but i was wondering if you know any options to run it directly in the cloud ? Also , i found some tutorials where they say to wrap all the code in an infinite loop and add a timer , and once you run the script it will stay active as a background process,
I just started working with scripts and automation , so i would really like to know your opinion on the best way to run the script automatically . Thanks a lot

Comment: What about jenkins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if that is what you are looking for, but (if you are on windows) you could attach your program to your autostart.  Probably your Startup Folder: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: Thanks man, i will try to , basically i want a script to always run in the background , without me manually pressing start each day

Answer (score 1):

If this is on a unix-based OS, check out `cron` ([this](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) is a pretty good guide). You can schedule it to run your python script daily.

Comment: Hy man , i am running on Windows 10 , this is the work computer , but thanks anyway

Comment: Perhaps this then https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

If you schedule in your computer, i think it may not be proper solution. It's better to deploy it on any cloud platforms & schedule at any particular time.

I personally suggest `Heroku`, I'm using it for running multiple scripts for free. You can use `scheduler addon` for scheduling scripts to run at particular time as well. Please refer to `heroku` documentation & get started! Note: The script may run more time than you expected, please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980849/how-to-make-a-python-script-to-run-only-on-specific-time-on-heroku) to fix this.

Comment: Hy man, thanks this i was looking for , i will get into the documentation . Thanks again